# Redirect to external Website using Blazor Server

Tags: c#, redirect, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor-server website and I am trying to redirect the user away from my website to an external one f. e. https://www.google.com

I already tried using the NavigationManager, as I used it when redirecting between my sites but it didn't work.
`NavManager.NavigateTo("www.google.com");`

This already took me hours of trying and googling and I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was what i was looking for, do you want to add it as a solution? I will mark it.

Comment: Same problem here, it happens only in Firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NavigationManager.NavigateTo` works for absolute and relative URI.

Try adding the protocol: `https://www.google.com`

[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.navigateto?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an anchor tag with an href.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Click to navigate.</a>
```

Comment: Not if Herzog is trying to achieve the redirection as part of a C# function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to JavaScript:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", ""https://www.google.com/"", "_blank");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help, but i don't want to open the page in a new tab. Is there a way to stay in the existing tab?